# Having problems with nav bar

Tags: css

I am having problems making my nav bar stick to the right hand side of the page (whilst still in the 1040px container). I want the nav bar to be in the same line as the header 'EJHARRIS TUTORING' but be on the right

here is the code:

style sheet:

```
.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;

}

.head .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;


}

.nav-wrapper{
    
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;



}


li{
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px;
    position:relative;

    }
```

html:

```
<div class="head"> 

  <nav class="container">
    <div class="main-header">
        <h1><span class = 'EJHARRIS'>EJHARRIS</span> Tutoring</h1>
    </div>


  
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav-about"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-pricing"><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="nav-contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: It's helpful if you can make it into an executable snippet by using the code snippet option.

Answer (score 1):

Add `justify-content: space-between;` or, if you want some space to the left and right as well, `justify-content: space-around` to the `.container`

Answer (score 0):

add this style...

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space between;
 }
```

If you want there to be a little space between the element and the end put in "space-around" instead of "space-between".